# Multi part upload file servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

How can I upload files and get other paramaters of a form? I want to handle multi part requests in Java servlet.

Answer (score 12):

To browse and select a file for upload you need a `<input type="file">` field in the form. As stated in the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) you need to use the `POST` method and the enctype attribute of the form has to be set to [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

```
<form action="uploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

After submitting such a form the form data is available in multipart format in the `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()`. For testing(!) purposes you can read the stream using the following snippet:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

You however need to *parse* the stream byte by byte (instead of char by char). Prior to the fresh new [Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html) API, the standard Servlet API didn't provide any builtin facilities to parse them. The normal form fields are also not available the usual `request.getParameter()` way, they are included in the multipart form data stream.

If you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet (which is only bit less than 2 monts old), then you need to parse the stream yourself. Parsing such a stream requires precise background knowledge of how multipart form data requests are [specified and structured](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html). To create a perfect multipart parser you'll have to write a lot of code. But fortunately there's the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) which has proven its robustness with years. Carefully read both the [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) and [Frequently Asked Questions](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html) to find code examples and learn how to use it to an optimum degree (take MSIE into account!).

Comment: Thanks for posting info on Servlet 3.0 here as an FYI, even though as you pointed out, it's highly unlikely the asker would be using it. I wasn't aware the 3.0 spec finally filled this gaping hole.

Comment: BufferedReader reader = request.getReader(); //..a bit shorter

Comment: To use Servlet 3.0 we need web server that supports Java EE 6.0... which would you advise?? Does tomcat support it...? Or is GlassFish V3 a better option when we use Java SE 6.0

Comment: @S.M.09 You don't explicitly need JEE6. Just a Servlet 3.0 container is enough. For example Tomcat 7.0. You can of course also go ahead with Glassfish 3. It also supports Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Does tomcat 6.0.26 support the Servlet3.0....??? I successfully did  upload file and some parameters to servers with Glassfish v3....I used `javax.servlet.http.Part=request.getPart()` to get file and a filename I passed.... But that didn't work when I switched to tomcat 6.0.26 from glasfish 3...

Comment: @S.M.09 Tomcat 6.0 is not the same as Tomcat 7.0 :) http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1**

Read adatapost's post.

**Step 2**

Check out the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) project.

There's a similarly workable solution by O'Reily, but its license of use requires you buy a book, and even that requirement is so poorly articulated that I won't benefit it with yet another link.

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**

set enctype form tag attribute.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ....>
   <input type="file" id="file1" name="file"/>
   .... other stuff
</form>
```

**Step-2**

Read Justin's post.

Comment: please, could you describe your step-2 more precisely "Read Justin's post **step 2**". I am stuck in an infinite loop. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Thanks for comment. The second step describes the use of **Commons FileUpload** API.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with **enctype="multipart/form-data"** we can not use request.getParameter() directly

Now to deal with the problem

Now, for uploading a file to the server, there can be various ways. But, I am going to use MultipartRequest class provided by oreilly. For using this class you must have **cos.jar** file.

```
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet 
{  

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)                     throws ServletException, IOException 
    {           
        MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"d:/new");  
        out.print("successfully uploaded");  
    }  
}
```

this will upload your file to d:/new

**Now to retrive parameter of multipart request**
you have to use `FilenameUtils` class and `getOriginalFileName()` method of `MultipartRequest` class.

```
String file = FilenameUtils.getName(req.getOriginalFileName("myfile"))+"\\";
String message = req.getParameter("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for IE7 and below. Apparently you need to add another attribute to your form encoding ="multipart/form-data"