# Java-blueimp jquery file upload List<FileItem> is empty?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, struts2, blueimp, multiple-file-upload

I used Jquery file upload with backend java.
Am getting

```
if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) is true.
```

but

```
List<FileItem> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
```

returns empty.I have not accessed request parameters before.

I google it and found change from `/*` to  `/*.action` in web.xml will solve the problem. But by this change the struts2 project is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That change makes no sense, both values ( `*/` and `/*.action`) are wrong, it should be `/*`.
2. You should never parse a Multipart Request by yourself, especially when there are tools out there like Apache Commons FileUpload doing it for you, most likely better than you. [Quoting BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2199254/1654265):

   > Parsing such a stream requires precise background knowledge of how multipart form data requests are specified and structured. To create a perfect multipart parser you'll have to write a lot of code. But fortunately there's the Apache Commons FileUpload which has proven its robustness with years.
3. Struts2 already handles that. You only need to understand how the file upload process works in Struts2.

   Try [with a single file in an `<s:file/>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15968166/1654265) first, then [with multiple files in a `<s:file/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265) , and finally add **Blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload** to the equation.

   Notice that with external libraries, it *might* be necessary to make small modifications, [like in the case of **Dropzone.js**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080212/1654265) (drag and drop uploader).

Comment: Thanks for your information.I tried <s:file/> with multiple inputs and its working fine. Am trying to implement basic ui from jquery.so i added all the required js from jquery and the front end is working fine.In main.js its calling jquery-fileupload.js.Do i want to change jquery-fileupload.js according to sturts2 as like Dropzone.js? As far now multipart content is receiving in the request.Please advice me futher.

Comment: Examine the network output: if it acts like dropzone.js, then change it as described in that answer. Struts2 don't want those [] in the multipart request. Does it work with 1 file, btw ?

Comment: Thank you so much. I can get file in action.Its working with jquery-fileupload.js with any change.I just removed "  <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">5000000</param>
        </interceptor-ref> "  from struts.xml